# Xamarin.Forms connect with Mac Agent

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Mac at macincloud hired, I can also via Remote Desktop Connection on joining, but I can not connect to the Mac in the cloud to Xamarin Mac Agent. It stucks here:
[image]

Comment: Have you contacted mac in cloud support? Have you double checked your firewall settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To connect Visual Studio to Xamarin Mac Agent you need the Remote Build Add-on which enables you to use SSH.

Here is their [support article](https://support.macincloud.com/support/solutions/articles/8000040392-visual-studio-cannot-to-connect-to-xamarin-studio) about this. If you missed this you need create a ticket with our Support Help Desk to have this feature enabled.